# Wordpress update_post_meta wrong serialize

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

given this `meta_value`:

```php
$new_meta_value = array (
    [244] => array
        (
            'course' => 244,
            'teacher' => array
                (
                    [0] => 608
                    [1] => 238
                ),
            'classroom' => 279,
            'price' => '300',
            'duration' => '01:30',
            'break' => '00:00',
            ),
);
```

after `update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value)` the serialized result:

```php
a:1:{i:0;a:9:{s:9:"teacher";i:1;s:9:"classroom";i:279;s:7:"course";i:244;s:8:"duration";s:5:"01:30";s:14:"break";s:5:"00:00";s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2019-02-20";s:10:"start_time";s:5:"13:30";s:5:"price";d:300;s:10:"exec_order";i:3;}}
```

the `teacher` gets only one value 0, as the index `[0]`

`var_dump` result:

> array (size=1) 254 => array (size=6) 'course' => int 254 'teacher' => array (size=2) 0 => string '608' (length=3) 1 => string '236' (length=3) 'classroom' => string '279' (length=3) 'price' => string '200' (length=3) 'duration' => string '02:00' (length=5) 'break' => string '00:00' (length=5)

Comment: Hello, Can you please share the var_dump() (instead of print_r) of your object before update_post_meta?

Comment: it's a multiple select field like "select[teachers][254][]"